# Can't create a new WebOS TV Project (no templates)

Tags: webos, lg

I installed the WebOS TV IDE on Mac from the LG downloads site. But when I run the WebOSTV IDE and click on New/WebOS TV Project, the dialog doesn't have any templates, so even if I provide a name, I can't go to the next step. Any idea how I would fix this or why it is broken in the first place?

Also, I downloaded a sample WebOS application, but I can't find any way in the WebOS IDE to open an existing project or import it. Thanks for any help.

Also, I registered as an LG Developer, but even when signed in to their Forums, I don't see any controls whatsoever for posting a new question--does anyone have any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, try using the CLI, `ares-generate -t moonstone-2017 appname`.
If that doesn't work, try to reinstall webOS SDK completely.
I hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, I uninstalled, then made sure I had Virtual Box installed (but had to install the latest, 5.2 -- it wouldn't let me install the very old version requested by the LG install instructions page.) I also made sure to restart my computer. So I can now see the templates in the IDE.

Comment: Cool, I'm glad that you were able to resolve the issue. :)
Please note that LG just released a new version of their SDK, 4.0. I recommend you to check out that as well (as it deprecated some templates).